# In Matrix Reloaded, what are the 'traffic control' people connected to?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix-reloaded

The scene that I am referring to is the one in which the Nebuchadnezzar comes to Zion for the first time in the film (after the all captains meeting in the Matrix).

In the control room where the women in white guide the ship home, there are some people (4 if I remember correctly) who are shown to be lying on a couch like surface within the control room itself and are plugged in.

The camera never lingers on them for very long - but they are very clearly shown a couple of times.

If I understand correctly, people cannot broadcast from within Zion - but need to find a secure broadcast facility outside.

So what are these people connected to? Is there any relevance to it? Seems like a decent amount of work to have people shown plugged in - if it does not mean anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It relates to the training areas of the first movie.

If you recall, the ships are there in order to broadcast a *'hacker signal'* into the Matrix in order to get their people inside it.  This requires them to travel a great distance away from Zion.  From this we can deduce that this is ***not*** the Matrix.

Further, recall that where they trained Neo (and themselves, for that matter) is essentially a Local-only (LAN only) version of the Matrix where they could create whatever they pleased (called *The Construct*).

This area that these 'Gatekeepers' appear to be plugged into is a similar Construct.  It gives them computers and a database and all other kinds of control over the gates and who does/does not have access to Zion.

As far as meaning and how much work it requires, I cannot say that this all seems practical, nor does it seem likely that they should be doing this, but such is the way of this series.

Comment: Hmm .. I thought as much - that they would be connected to the Construct. However, the entire setup (of showing people connected to the construct) from the Control room seemed too much of an effort to me - hence I thought that there would be some other explanation. Thanks for the quick response! :)

Comment: @saurabhj yeah,there really isn't much beyond that unfortunately.  I do agree that it seems too much effort.